# sync of Android app with google Docs`

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am new to android .in my app there is a module sync of my app with google docs...can any one help we with good tutorial links which makes me some fast building ....I hope i have good stuff hare please help me Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [`google-api-java-client`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android) library which supports Android. There are some examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks for reply .....i tried with that ...but it was some  difficult to me to understand .please share me as some tutorials .....